# Form validation when select option from another select

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, forms, elementor

I have a form with 2 select. When a user chooses option from a Select B, it display a specific value from select A using this script :

```
var $ = jQuery;
 $(document).ready(function () {
     
    $('#ville_livraison').change(function(){
    
    $('#ville_livraison option[value*="74890"]').addClass('cp-74890');
         
    if ($('#ville_livraison option:selected').hasClass('cp-74890')) {
        $('#code_postal_livraison').val("74890");
    }
    
    })
    
    $('#ville_livraison').trigger('change');
});
```

select A = #code_postal_livraison and select B = #ville_livraison. The issue that I have is the form doesn't submit when the value is selected this way, it's like no option is selected. How can I validate the form even if the user doesn't manually choose an option ?

You can check it [here](https://festichablais.fr/produit/produit-1606/). The form is on the right and you have to check "se faire livrer + on le récupère" to see select elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your select tag with #ville_livraison has a required attribute, so it is required that this input has a value when submitting the form. If the value is empty the browser will give a validation notice. Every option in #ville_livraison works, except Ville. This happens because Ville's option tag has a value attribute, but this value attribute has no value. Try adding "Ville" as a value to this option tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but even if I add a value to both select default option, it doesn't work.

`$('#code_postal_livraison option:first').val("Code postal");` and `$('#ville_livraison option:first').val("Ville");`

Just select an option from select #ville_livraison and press submit. Nothing happen because no value is manually selected from select #code_postal_livraison but the field value is good.

Comment: You fixed the first issue, but now you are facing the next issue. I don't know exactly what is causing this new issue, because your JS is minified so that makes it hard to debug. The js is coming from jet form builder, so the issue is in there. However, I can help you fix the issue: If you trigger a change event on the #code_postal_livraison select, your form will submit. An easy fix would be: `$('[name="options_livraison"]').on('change', () => $('[name="code_postal_livraison"]').trigger('change'));`. Best would be if you track down the issue in the plugin, otherwise just use my code snippet.

Comment: If you want to keep it simple, simply add `$('[name="code_postal_livraison"]').trigger('change')`  below `$('#ville_livraison').trigger('change');` from your example. So you trigger the change event onload, making the form submitable.

Comment: Yes your first snippet works for what I'm looking for but now the user can select option from `#ville_livraison` then change select option from `#code_postal_livraison`. Is it possible to reset select `#ville livraison` to option 1 "Ville" when select `#code_postal_livraison` change ? 
I tried `$('#code_postal_livraison').change(function(){ $('#ville_livraison').val("") })` but it doesn't work.
If it could help you, options "Code postal" and "Ville" are placeholders, I don't want them to be real options.